# My offline website appears differently than my offline website (pictures won't display)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am hosting my website through Github. I am not profficient in HTML or CSS, but there are significant resources on line to help me get by. The issue is that I tried to make a slideshow for my website. When I click on the file on my computer, it opens up offline in my browser and everything looks exactly how I want it, i.e. pictures displaying. When I uploaded all my code onto github however and tried to go on my website online, the pictures in the slideshow did not display. I will link the github and the code below. I used the W3 schools code for the slideshows, and this is evident in the code that you can see on github. Also below is the html/java used for one of the slideshows. I apoligize in advance for what are probably terrible coding practices, inability to post correctly on the site, etc. The css is not really displaying correctly so please see the github for that. https://github.com/laservader/prebarbar.github.io

what it looks like online:

[image: what it looks like online]

what it looks like offline:

[image: what it looks like offline]

online:

[image: online]

offline:

[image: offline]

```
<!-- Container for the image gallery -->
    <div class="container">
      <script>
      var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
    $(".slideshow > img:gt(0)").hide();
    </script>
      <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_6523.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_6867.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_7116.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_7139.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_7154.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
          <img src="img_7185.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


      <!-- Thumbnail images -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_6523.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_6867.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_7116.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_7139.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_7154.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_7185.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      showSlides(slideIndex);
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you upload your images aswell to github?Maybe your path is wrong.

Comment: Yeah the images are all uploaded, other images are displaying well on the website, and some just added, its specifically the slideshow aspects that are not working

Comment: You spelled the file paths all lowercase, but the files you uploaded aren't all lowercase.

Comment: yes, but this is not an issue for the other images, unless github just works differently than my computer, I am trying it right now, hopefully its that easy, ok that seemed to have been the issue lol, Thanks!

Comment: hey siguza how do i mark you as answering my question

Comment: @theprebarbar, you cannot. since this is a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually a .jpg file but one with a .JPG extension, if it's online it might not be able to appear because of that